# PSWindowsUpdate doesn't work in a service application on windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, vbscript

I have a C++ application that call different powershell commands and puts the output into a json file. It's installed with a VBS script, that automatically imports the PSWindowsUpdate module. And it all works fine, except when I'm on a Windows 11 machine - where the command just decided to output a null.
Snippet of importing the module:

```
        If Not (oFSO.FolderExists(strModulePath)) Then
            objFile.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & " Installing PSWU" & vbCrLf
            oFSO.CreateFolder strModulePath
            oFSO.CopyFile psdir, strModulePath
            objFile.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & " Création du PSWU - force" & vbCrLf
        End If
        objFile.Write FormatDateTime(Now) & " Importing the new module" & vbCrLf
        objShell.Run("powershell.exe -Command ""Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate""")
```

Snippet of the working powershell command:

```
 ConvertTo-Json @(Get-WindowsUpdate  | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select Title, KB })
[
    {
        "Title":  "2023-05 Aperçu de la mise à jour cumulative de .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 et 4.8.1 Windows 10 Version 22H2 pour x64 (KB5026958)",
        "KB":  "KB5026958"
    },
    {
        "Title":  "AOC International (Europe) GmbH - Monitor, Other hardware - AOC 2475W",
        "KB":  ""
    },
    {
        "Title":  "Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200 v6/7th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) Host Bridge/DRAM Registers - 590F",
        "KB":  ""
    }
]
```

Just to precise, the command works just fine if i execute it inside an application rather than a service, and if i execute it by myself directly in powershell. It's when it's put as a service that it refuses to work. All other commands that should need same perms or more work. I sent a mail to the creator but he never responded :(

Comment: Not familiar with, just guessing: Maybe MS changed the way modules are found within W11, you might need to install it at another location or maybe somehow provide the path to the module – or grant the system process running the service access rights to. If you can run from within an application maybe you might start that one from within the service? Might require impersonation of a user being able to access the module (or impersonate before running it directly).

Comment: You might be right - maybe the services access modules differently in W11 than in the past? But I don't think it's a rights problems, as it has no problems executing different commands. Also, the 'app' in question is the same thing as the service, just without it being a service, so calling it would be redondant (and would make me do much more work than needed)

Comment: Well, agree, the separate application is overkill... Might still indeed be the rights, though – the module and powershell itself are not the same, the service might be able to access one but not the other. Being able to run from PS directly or within an application doesn't contradict, be aware that services are run by the local system account while you run it from within your personal user account, both possibly having different rights (like e.g. having granted execution right only to owner of the module). Impersonation *might* be away to work around, you'd need to try out.

Comment: What account are you using to run the service?  When you add the service to windows there is an option to run with an account.  The account has permission levels and an environment that the service will use.  I would check event viewer to see if any errors are occurring when the service is running.

Comment: The core of Windows 11 is really no different than Windows 10 (i.e. services work the same). I would focus on configuration differences that may be responsible. Can you post more details/code showing how you start your service?